# django-tables2 custom column

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I'm working now on my first Django project. I want to render results table which contains all fields from **Priekabos** model and one custom column from **Grafikas** which should contain something similar to:

```
SELECT max(kada_moketi) FROM grafikas WHERE priekabos_id = ?
```

Whatever I try from examples nothing works. Should I write another view function with that custom query:

```
(Grafikas.objects.filter(priekabos_id=1)
```

neither with:

```
.aggregate(Max('kada_moketi')
```

neither with:

```
.latest('kada_moketi')
```

worked for me I created a new table class in tables.py which later PriekabosTable will inherit? That didn't work for me too.

Here's my code:

**models.py**

```
class Grafikas(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    mokejimo_nr = models.IntegerField()
    kada_moketi = models.DateField()
    priekabos = models.ForeignKey('Priekabos', models.DO_NOTHING)

class Priekabos(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    sutarties_nr = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=45, verbose_name='Sut. Nr.')
    nuomos_pradz = models.DateField()
    sutarties_trukme = models.IntegerField()
```

**views.py**

```
def priekabos_table(request):
    table = PriekabosTable(Priekabos.objects.all())
    RequestConfig(request, paginate={'per_page': 20}).configure(table)
    return render(request, 'isperkamoji_nuoma/priekabos_table.html', {'table': table})
```

**tables.py**

```
class PriekabosTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = Priekabos
        attrs = {"class": "paleblue"}
        fields = ('id', 'sutarties_nr', 'nuomos_pradz')
```

For better understanding, here's 'grafikas' table:
[MySQL 'grafikas' table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3b3ux.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you might be able to fetch the extra field using [`annotate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset).

```
from django.db.models import Max
queryset = Priekabos.objects.annotate(max_kada_moketi=Max('grafikas__kada_moketi'))
table = PriekabosTable(queryset)
```

Remember to add the field to your table.

```
class PriekabosTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = Priekabos
        attrs = {"class": "paleblue"}
        fields = ('id', 'sutarties_nr', 'nuomos_pradz', 'max_kada_moketi')
```

Comment: Thank you! I was stuck for two days. Definitely I need to learn more about querying in Django.